# Flutter clicking on OnTap not working (Website)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use onTap to change the appearance of a container when pressed however the issue I am having is that clicking on it right now does nothing.

The following is my code:
HomePage:

```
child: SubscribeButton(
                          onTap: buttonPressed,
                          isButtonPressed: isButtonPressed,
                        ),
```

Method:

```
bool isButtonPressed = false;

  void buttonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      if (isButtonPressed = false) {
        isButtonPressed = true;
      } else if (isButtonPressed = true) {
        isButtonPressed = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Button:

```
  Class SubscribeButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final onTap;
  bool isButtonPressed;

  SubscribeButton({this.onTap, required this.isButtonPressed});

     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: onTap,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            child: Text(
              isButtonPressed ? "Pressed" : "Not Pressed",
              style: isButtonPressed
                  ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium
                  : Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ), ...
```

It will correctly display the text if I manually change the boolean value however clicking on the button itself does nothing. I checked for overlaps and other things however did not find anything.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Good old = vs == problem:

```
// Change the next line to "if (isButtonPressed == false)"
if (isButtonPressed = false) {
        isButtonPressed = true;
// Similar issue
      } else if (isButtonPressed = true) {
        isButtonPressed = false;
      }
```

I didn't spot any other problem, but maybe there are. Fix this first and try again.

Comment: My god I feel stupid, sometimes a second pair of eyes is all you need. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: That's why they recommend pair programming lol

Comment: Also, I'd suggest simplifying your code a lot (so you'll avoid such headaches next time): in your `buttonPressed` method, simply write `isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed` instead of the long `if-else` chain.